# GCM notifies not reaching device having google play service 6.5.99

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

1. Used [Master commonsguy GCM client code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/ef269a785353b9dc2704aee9f7bc3b16abf186cc/Push/GCMClient2) and trying GCM notifies.
2. Works well if i upgrade to latest GPS apk i.e 8.1.15.
3. Device has inbuild GPS apk version 6599000(6.5.99) and devices fail to receive GCM messages.
4. `int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(applicationContext);`

resultCode is 2 which is [SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED)

5. GPS lib project(D:\andySDK\extras\google\google_play_services) version is 7571000.If i make it to 6599000 i get error need 7571000 found 6599000

Whatsapp in the same devcies(GPS 6.5.99) is able to receive the GCM without any issues. How do i make a GCM client app which works in device which has old GPS.?

Comment: are you showing the dialog that tells the user they need to update google play services?

Comment: @tyczj Yeah doing it..but hows whatsapp working is mystery..6.5.99 GPS is dec 2014 it should work..

Comment: why does it matter what another app does, you should always be targeting the newest version of google play services anyway because of bug fixes and security fixes

Comment: "newest version of google play services anyway because of bug fixes and security fixes" Agree..But there is service outage in mycase here right..ii.e if user does not upgrade..intention is to code for lowest GPS and hoping forward compatibility..

Comment: @tyczj trying to know whatsapp design to achieve this..

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder just curious, how do you know if Whatsapp is using 6.5.99?

Comment: I meant whatsapp with device GPS 6.5.99 worked well..generall idea what google suggest is to use latest GPS as reference sdk to compile and deploy..

Answer (score -1):

GCM needs some requirments to work properly. in your case I think you are using `GCMNetworkMAnager` which needs Google Play Services version 7.5.0+ installed on the device.

So, you could use `AlarmManager` instead, since that's been around since android 1.0