# Android: GCM vs FCM (Google Play Services upgrade vs Application upgrade)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently using Google Play Services and in turn, the GCM feature of it to receive notification from my app server. I know newer Google Play Services gets newer APIs and makes the feature more efficient.

1. Old experiemnt observations: [GCM notifies not reaching device having google play service 6.5.99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720137/gcm-notifies-not-reaching-device-having-google-play-service-6-5-99)
2. What is the min Google play services required for GCM to work? Is it "Google Play Services 3.1" (https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/05/android-at-google-io-2013-keynote-wrapup.html)?
3. With Google play services getting updated very often, do I need to update Google play services version and release my app to play store often as well?
4. How do I make GCM work even without updating to the latest version or should I force the user to update by putting up *update dialog*?

   ex: old

   ```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:3.1.0
   ```

   to

   ```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.0
   ```

PS: I'm yet to move to FCM. Is it the same case with FCM though? Do I need to update my app very often by updating the latest FCM version in gradle? i.e.:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
```

Comment: Straight market abuse from Google, they are forcing developers to go though Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

1. (*This doesn't seem to be a question*)
2. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any explicitly mentioned version of Google Play Services that is needed for GCM to work (and it would probably take time to test which ones it does). The known requirements are just as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).
3. Not necessarily. If you don't need to use the latest version, then you don't have to. It's just preferred and often advised since using the latest version often has the bug fixes on behaviors from previous versions.
4. It's expected to work so long as you were able to properly implement it on the client side (this includes importing the correct library versions). [Checking for the Google Play Services SDK](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-play) is ***optional***, and is only strongly suggested to be done by Apps that strongly rely on Play Services.

   With that said, GCM has been existing for quite a *long* time and I'm pretty sure that most versions of the Play Services is able to handle it, much more if you're using FCM.

It is strongly suggested that you proceed with using FCM, since similar to using the latest version of Play Services, it contains fixes on bugs that occurred on GCM. And same case with GCM, you don't have to update it very often.

Guess you could think of the "*If it works, don't fix it*" saying

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with FCM. Push notifications are relies to token that generated by your **device id**.

On the other hand, device ids are changed whenever user makes factory reset, adding new user and update system version. User, Device and System Infos are the variables in token generation.

For making your push notifications work, you should handle them. This is the why most of people are having problems why their push notifications did not work... You need to register BroadcastReceivers to specific events to update your invalidated existing token.

**What is the advantage of using FCM?**

These problems are covered by already and its ready-to-go api.

Also you have a nice panel(firebase console) to send push notification to your users. You do not need even write a code to fire a notifications.

You can ask your users to update their Play Services by using [GooglePlayServicesUtil](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil) and [GoogleApiAvailability.](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability)

Most of applications are already doing scheduled updates for updating dependencies and fixes. Its really user-friendly.

Good luck

Emre

Answer (score 0):

2. GCM (and FCM) works even before Google Play services 3.1, so pretty much any version. That said, the currently officially supported version is from Google Play services 4.0 (older versions still work, but we might stop supporting it in the future).
3. You don't need to update the libraries in your app every Google Play services update. Every update is compatible with older libraries.
   That said, it's good practice to update to benefit from the bugfixes (sometimes if it's a small bugfix it's not mentioned in the changelog)
4. no need to force the user to update Google Play services for GCM / FCM.
   (For other Google Play services libraries it might be needed but it should be handled automatically by those libraries)
5. I strongly reccomend to update to FCM to benefits from the new features and bugfixes

PS: when you use multiple Google Play services libraries (or Firebase libraries) be careful to use the same version of all the library. this is a hard requirement.